# Can Sinkhorn Distance calculate the difference between two sets of point clouds of different sizes?

Tags: point-clouds

Can Sinkhorn Distance calculate the difference between two sets of point clouds of different sizes? Why?
Sinkhorn Distance can optimally achieve the results of EMD. EMD requires that the two sets of point clouds have the same size.

I called the existing Sinkhorn Distance code library and they don't require the two sets of point clouds to be the same size, but I don't know why.